# Remove appends, once an onclick happens

Tags: jquery, api, for-loop

im am trying to use a for loop to append two temperatures based on weather api and display them based on user input, however if the user searches a new location again, the previous appended temperature is still there.

Is there a way to remove the previous append if the user searches for a new location, which means new temperatures will be appended and displayed?`

```js
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 var tempts = Math.floor(data.list[i].temp.day);
//temperatures is an empty array to push into
 temperatures.push(tempts);
    $('#weatherDiv').append("<p><b>" + random[i] + "</b>" +"<br />Temperature: " + temperatures[i] + "F</p>")
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps

```
$('#weatherDiv').html(""); // empty container before filling it

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
var tempts = Math.floor(data.list[i].temp.day);
//temperatures is an empty array to push into
temperatures.push(tempts);
$('#weatherDiv').append("<p><b>" + random[i] + "</b>" +"<br />Temperature:     " + temperatures[i] + "F</p>")
 }
```